# FactoryGirl.build not returning an object per definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I have a `User` class with a `save` method which makes a change to one of the user instance attributes. Specifically, each user has an `options` hash that gets one of its values deleted during the save process.

I have an rspec test with 2 context groups. Each group creates a new `@user` object using `FactoryGirl.build(:user)`. When I call `@user.save` in the first context group, the attribute change occurs as expected. However, the second time that `FactoryGirl.build(:user)` gets called, it doesn't return a User object according to the FactoryGirl definition. It returns a user object with an `options` hash that is missing the same value that gets deleted during the save process. This object is not valid, and as a result `@user.save` fails the second time.

UPDATE: I tried changing the variable names and I still have the same problem. The issue seems to be with the FactoryGirl :user factory being modified somehow during the first example, resulting in the second example failing.

Below is a simplified version of my code. Whichever context group is executed second ("with avatar" or "without avatar") when run randomly by Rspec is the one that fails. I have used `puts` in both cases to confirm that the second `@user` has a bad `options` hash, and causes the test to fail.

```
describe "save" do
  context "with avatar" do
    before(:context) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
      puts @user
      @save_result = @user.save
    end
    after(:context) do
      delete_user(@user)
    end
    it "should return true" do
      expect(@save_result).to be true
    end
  end
  context "without avatar" do
    before(:context) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, avatar: nil)
      puts @user
      @save_result = @user.save
    end
    after(:context) do
      delete_user(@user)
    end
    it "should return true" do
      expect(@save_result).to be true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you will need to also post the `FactoryGirl` definition and the code that reads and changes the `options` hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the `options` hash gets reused.

According to the [FactoryGirl readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes), when you want to add a hash attribute to a FactoryGirl definition and that hash is dynamic (i.e. not the same among all created instances), you need to wrap it in a block:

Instead of:

```
factory :user do
  options { option1: 1, option2: 2 }
end
```

You need to do:

```
factory :user do
  options { { option1: 1, option2: 2 } }
end
```